# Unwind Segue not being performed after shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier UIAlertController

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uiviewcontroller, uialertcontroller

I have an unwind segue from a `UIViewController` named `DetailViewController` to `MainViewController` defined as (within `MainViewController`):

```
@IBAction func deleteItemUnwind(sender: UIStoryboardSegue)
{
    let sourceViewController = sender.sourceViewController
}
```

In the DetailView, I have the button that should perform the segue connected to the scene exit with the name `deleteItemUnwindSegue`, and in DetailViewController I have the `prepareForSegue` change the value of some variables. This works fine. The problem is, I have the following code in `DetailViewController`

```
    override func shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier(identifier: String!, sender: AnyObject!) -> Bool {

    if (identifier == "deleteItemUnwindSegue") {

        let deleteItemAlert: UIAlertController = UIAlertController(title: "Delete item", message: "Are you sure you want to delete this item?", preferredStyle: .ActionSheet)

        let cancelAction: UIAlertAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .Cancel) { action -> Void in
            return false
        }
        deleteItemAlert.addAction(cancelAction)

        let deleteItemAction: UIAlertAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Yes", style: .Destructive) { action -> Void in
            return true
        }
        deleteItemAlert.addAction(deleteChoreAction)

        self.presentViewController(deleteItemAlert, animated: true) {

        }
    }
    return true
}
```

And while the `prepareForSegue` code works, the Unwind segue *itself* is not triggered to dismiss the view. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out that(after reading up on `UIAlertController`) the moment after the alert is displayed, the code after it is carried out, so it wold automatically give false every time. I was able to bypass this by creating a generic `First Responder` to `Exit` unwind segue, and have the button item trigger the segue.